# Corda - Transaction Metadata

Tags: corda

We have a use-case in Corda where we want to add metadata to a transaction that is visible to all counter-parties. With respect in this case, we can't add this information to the state because

- Not all states in the transaction are visible to all transaction counter-parties
- It's not relevant to the state itself

Also, it would not make sense to build out separate states and contracts to get this information (essentially leaning on the type system to gain additional information) because

- The states/contracts would be identical
- This is a poor use of object-oriented programming

To give an idea of what we're trying to do, consider the Corda IOU demo. Upon issuance of an IOU state, we can specify an amount of currency, but we can't specify any contextual metadata about *why* we're issuing IOU states.

What we want is something where we could add even just a simple string like:

- "You sold us apples"
- "You sold us oranges"

The only option I can see for this is using attachments, but it seems like overkill for such a small piece of data.

The other thing I've seen are functions `addTransactionNote` and `getTransactionNotes` These would be perfect if transaction notes were distributed to counter-parties, but this appears not to be the case.

What other options do we have for adding simple metadata to transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add transaction note to yourself and other counterparties participants to this transaction by using below subflow in your main business flow.

```
object TxNoteFlow {
    @InitiatingFlow    
    class Initiator(val txNote: TxNote,
                    val counterParties: Collection<Party> = listOf()) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {            
            serviceHub.vaultService.addNoteToTransaction(txNote.txId, txNote.msg)

            //Distribute the transaction-note to counter parties.
            val flowSessions = mutableSetOf<FlowSession>()
            counterParties.forEach { flowSessions.add(initiateFlow(it)) }
            flowSessions.forEach { session -> session.send(txNote) }
        }

    }

    @InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
    class Acceptor(flowSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {
            flowSession.receive<TxNote>().unwrap {
                serviceHub.vaultService.addNoteToTransaction(it.txId, it.msg)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> And call this flow as `subflow` at end of your business flow, after a successful commitment of a transaction.

```
 @InitiatingFlow    
    class BusinessInitiator(val state: SomeState) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {            
            //Build the transaction.
            val txb=...
            .....

            //Commit signed transaction to ledger.
            val stx=FinalityFlow(tx, ..)

            //Transaction notes.
            subflow(TxNoteFlow.Initiator(...))
        }

    }
```

Comment: this can only be done after the tx has been recorded.

Answer (score -1):

How about embedding the metadata in the command?

```
interface Commands : CommandData {
    data class Action(val metaData: Any) : Commands
}
```

Comment: @Kid101 because compared to the accepted solution, this feels hacky. Commands aren't intended to hold per-transaction metadata, so this would obscure intent.